# MUI DataGrid access formatted values from getDetailPanelContent

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

My project requirements say that on mobile screens we should be able to show only 2 columns (to prevent horizontal scroll) and the rest of the columns should be hidden under Master Detail as a list of key value pairs.

So I'm hiding all the columns except first and last

```js
  const getColumnVisibilityModel = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isMobile) return undefined;

    return props.columns.reduce((acc, col, idx) => {
      if (idx === 0 || idx === props.columns.length - 1) {
        acc[col.field] = true;
      } else {
        acc[col.field] = false;
      }

      return acc;
    }, {} as any);
  }, [props.columns]);
```

Then I extract the columns I need for the Master Detail panel:

```js
  const hiddenColumns = useMemo(() => {
    return getWithoutFirstAndLastArrayElements(props.columns);
  }, [props.columns]);
```

```js
   <DataGridPremium
      getDetailPanelContent={
        isMobile
          ? (params: GridRowParams) => {
              return <MasterDetailPanel hiddenColumns={hiddenColumns} {...params} />;
            }
          : undefined
      }
      getDetailPanelHeight={() => 'auto'}
      columnVisibilityModel={getColumnVisibilityModel()}
      {...props}
    />
```

And then in MasterDetail component I'm getting columns match to their values and render them as key - value

```js
function MasterDetailPanel({ hiddenColumns, ...params }: MasterDetailPanelProps) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Stack bgcolor={theme.palette.grayscale.white} pl={8} py={2} spacing={0.5}>
      {hiddenColumns.map((col) => {
        const label = col.headerName;
        const value = params.row[col.field];

        return <InfoItem label={label} value={value} />;
      })}
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

The problem is that `value` only shows the unformatted value.

So, my question is. How can I access the values that are actually rendered in the DataGrid ?